# Text Based Game, Enemy duplication

Tags: python

I'm making a text based game in python and I was wondering if anyone knows how to make multiply enemies. I already have the code for the room and the enemy inside but I want it to continue throwing enemies at the character when one dies.

```
class EnemyRoom(MapTile):

    def __init__(self, x, y, enemy):
        self.enemy = enemy
        super().__init__(x, y)

    def modify_player(self, the_player):
        if self.enemy.is_alive():
            the_player.hp = the_player.hp - self.enemy.damage
            print("Enemy does {} damage. You have {} HP remaining.".format(self.enemy.damage, the_player.hp))

    def available_actions(self):
        if self.enemy.is_alive():
            return [actions.Attack(enemy=self.enemy)]
        else:
            return self.adjacent_moves()


class MonsterRoom(EnemyRoom):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x, y, enemies.Monster())

    def intro_text(self):
        if self.enemy.is_alive():
            """
            A monster jumps in front of you!
            """
```

Comment: It would be very difficult to give you a good answer without first asking you a lot more questions. This isn't really a chat forum. Take the [tour] and see [ask].

Answer (score -1):

You could add a check in `modify_player` before damaging the player that revives or re-spawns the monster if it's not alive.

Comment: How would I write that out?

Comment: I would have to have more info about the Monster class, when and how it dies and what happens then. But if you cannot reproduce such simple logic I strongly recommend that you read a beginner's book. You'll advance much faster and there's plenty that are focused on gaming.